# ReadTextAsync returns null unless stepping through with breakpoint

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, I am writing to a file (20K ascii text file) using WriteTextAsync, then reading the same file using ReadTextAsync.
When I run with breakpoint, stepping through the ReadRawTextFromFile, it works fine.
When I run normally (without breakpoints), I get a null return from ReadTextAsync.
I don't get any Exceptions.
What can I do to get this to read the file.

```
// This is for writing the RawText
private async void WriteRawTextToFile(string fname, string textToWrite)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile localFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fname, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile, textToWrite);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WriteRawTextToFile Exception: '{e}'");
    }
}

private string TextFromFile;    // to get back from the file read
private async void ReadRawTextFromFile(string fname, string defaultString)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile localFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(fname);
        TextFromFile = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(localFile);        // get Text from the file
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
        TextFromFile = defaultString;
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you proved this, extraordinary claims need extraordinary proof

Comment: Do not use `async void`.

Comment: How do you verify that you get back `null` from `ReadTextAsync`? There's no code in your question that verifies this. Make sure you don't confuse `TextFromFile` is `null` with `ReadTextAsync` returned `null`, since timing-wise, because you used `async void`, by the time you try to read `TextFromFile`, `ReadTextAsync` may not yet have executed or returned. Also, `async void` is the same as "fire and forget", you obviously want results from it, so you cannot forget it, in which case `async void` is entirely wrong (and likely the cause of your problems as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to explain what @HenkHolterman mean in the comment,

`async` and `async Task` which doesn't have return type (void) is kind of not going well with Exception and throwable they're mean only for asynchronous event listener, but not with `async Task<T>` or `async T`, which have a return type, where if there any exception, the exception then will be passed to the caller through the return type. and also you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) about best practices on async and await

my suggestion are

1. make the `async` method have return type, `bool` or `Task<bool>` for example to indicates whether the method is successful doing its thing
2. you're doing this on UWP right ? i don't exactly remember (or maybe even know) about how UWP handles Storage/Disk I/O request, but you sure your code/app already have the required permissions ?
3. i don't know the underlying methods and such, but if the `WriteLines()` from `Console` doesn't work for outputting the error and such, try use `Debug.WriteLines()` from `System.Diagnostics` namespace. This might or might not your real issue regarding No exceptions printed out to the output window

also trying to explain what @MichaelRandal mean (also, from the comment)

You've made an 'extraordinary claims', if i may quote from the comment, regarding with breakpoints, because of this, we hope you to elaborate more, for example giving more information, maybe the stack output, breakpoints output and such, thus anyone who might want to answer or contribute doesn't have to keep asking for required information

Comment: An `async Task Method() {}` would be fine here. It's `async void Method() {}` that should be avoided almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) was great - I made it `Task`, or `Task<T>` all the was up to the event handler, and it works just as expected.  I now see why `async void` is not useful.